# @media screen for portrait and landscape

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am using a responsive template to build a website and i want to customize some parts of it for screens portrait and landscape (eg in iPhone). So i write in the css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {...}
```

and after this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {...}
```

i test my site with an [emulator](http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/) but in both cases the 2nd rule is triggered.. why? do i miss sth?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Because if the width is 240 for example, so:

240 <= 320 then 1st one is triggered.

and

240 <= 480 then 2nd one is triggered.

Please use `min-width` in addition to the second one :)

You can also use the built in `portrait` and `landscape`:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)
```

Comment: @yaylitzis, Please consider marking this as the correct answer, if you think it answers what you wanted :)